# conv_integer() vs to_integer()

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl, hardware

What's the difference between conv_integer() and to_integer() functions? Which one should I use?
I found on [forum](https://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?287130-difference-between-conv_integer-and-to_integer&p=1227526&viewfull=1#post1227526) that the libraries are different:

Function "conv_integer" defined in Synopsys Library : std_logic_arith, defined as:

- function CONV_INTEGER(ARG: UNSIGNED) return INTEGER;
- function CONV_INTEGER(ARG: SIGNED) return INTEGER;

Function "To_integer" defined in IEEE library:numeric_std, defined as:

- function TO_INTEGER (ARG: UNSIGNED) return INTEGER;
- function TO_INTEGER (ARG: SIGNED) return INTEGER;

Comment: [These two functions do the same thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnnlY.jpg). Synopsys package std_logic_arith is not part of the standard while the IEEE's package numeric_std is (-2008). It's common to find package std_logic_arith used in (dated) university courses and materials. Functions in IEEE specified packages are treated as producing locally static results, advantageous where static expressions are required (e.g. case expressions). Which is otherwise a matter of opinion.

Comment: The major difference as pointed out is that to_integer is standard and conv_integer is not. As @user1155120 also shows conv_integer is limited to 31 bit unsigned values. to_integer has no limit and therefore implementation defined (most currently will be limited to 31 bits). VHDL2019 mandates 64 bit integers, so max `ARG` size should be 63 bits for to_integer, but conv_integer will be forever locked at 31 bits.

Comment: Basically, for new code, don't use `std_logic_arith`; use `numeric_std` instead.